# Database restore does not retain emojis

Tags: mysql, mariadb, backup

I am doing a naïve database backup and restore like this:

```
SCHEMA=${2:-mindlevel}
DB_HOST=$1
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword -h$DB_HOST --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --complete-insert --no-create-info $SCHEMA -r ${SCHEMA}_backup.sql 
mysqladmin -uroot -ppassword -h$DB_HOST -f drop $SCHEMA &&
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h$DB_HOST --default-character-set=utf8mb4 < ${SCHEMA}_schema.sql &&
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h$DB_HOST $SCHEMA --default-character-set0=utf8mb4 < ${SCHEMA}_backup.sql
```

But all emojis that I had before the restore are shown as ?, but if I enter an emoji again it is stored and shown correctly.

I have tried having --default-character-set=utf8 but with the same result.

**UPDATE:**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE user;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(191) DEFAULT 'user.jpg',
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `level` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `created` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_active` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The backup file:

```
file mindlevel_backup.sql 
mindlevel_backup.sql: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

The top part of `mindlevel_backup.sql`:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change one line.
From:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h$DB_HOST $SCHEMA --default-character-set=utf8mb4 < ${SCHEMA}_backup.sql
```

To:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h$DB_HOST $SCHEMA --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -e "SET NAMES utf8mb4; SOURCE"${SCHEMA}"_backup.sql;"
```

I don't know why that worked, so if anyone care to explain that to me I'll update the answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, I only added "--default-character-set=utf8mb4" to my `mysqldump` command in order to make it work. (I wasn't specifying the charset before). I think you don't have to use "set names" if you use mysqldump instead of mysql.

Comment: as Tokeen said, using `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` when exporting and importing makes it work. This is: `mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 ... > dump.sql` and `mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 ... < dump.sql`

Answer (score 1):

The column in the table also needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the first part of `backup.sql`.

Comment: If the column wasn't utf8mb4 then it wouldn't be able to store the emoji correctly after the restore either? But I'll update my question with your requests.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  And do the debugging mentioned there.

Comment: I have done everything in there already. That is why I created a new question. It is so strange...

Comment: If `mindlevel_backup.sql` comes from `mysqldump`, it will start with a character set setting -- overriding your settings.  Check it.

Comment: Does it not respect the `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` which I have as a parameter?

Comment: @spydon - not the word "default".  That implies there may be ways to override it.  (There are.)

Comment: How confusing, how do I check what it starts with? Tried to google but to no avail. However that didn't seem to be the problem, but the problem seem to have been something with reading up the dump again (see my answer). Thanks a lot for your patience and help!

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant. That is even stranger, it does the same thing in there as I did manually in the `-e` parameter of my answer (updated the question).